# How to handle content for a new app?

Tags: user-expectation, interface, mobile-application

My app is new,and some field in my app need to present user generated data to user.So my question is,how to manage the content for the 1st-10th user?Since the app is new,therefore having no data,so how can I manage to present my app in the good way?

So for example,in the image below,the alphabet a - h represent different kind of options,let's say is a food that user like.So A- H is represent different kind of food that multiple user input to the app.

So my question is,my app is new,0 user now,so when the 1st - 10th user come in what should I show them if not a hard coded data ?And how to encourage them to input the food they like to the app?

Somebody please give me a little bit suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use empty states

Empty state is a concept that came up to solve this exact problem. It is fun, attractive, informative, even interactive and takes away the problem of "what to show when I have nothing to show"

For some examples, visit [this](http://emptystat.es/) site

[image: empty state example for a food app with interaction]